# Plotting a Skewed Distribution

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

I need to plot a slightly skewed dataset. I'd imagine there is a formula like:

```
f(x, mean, stddev, skew, ...etc) = y
```

But I can't find anything that specific. For example, I may get these parameters:

```
mean: 8.07
stddev: 1.18
pearson_skew: -0.64
```

and I'd like to plot a curve. I'm not sure I'm calculating the right parameters or if this is a bad idea all-together, so forgive my ignorance.

For context, the data is coming from a large dataset in a RDMS and the plot needs to be rendered on a browser (without access to the original dataset).

Comment: There are an infinite number of distributions that have a given mean, standard deviation, and skew.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Are other parameters that would help me summarize this dataset?

Comment: Your last Comment suggests you have a dataset and you want to fit it with parameters.  I don't think anyone would get that from the the way the Question is stated.  The body of your Question and its tags point toward *plotting* or *graphing*.  Can you connect up these loose threads for your Readers?

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the density of a skew-normal distribution can be done by the `dsn` function in the `sn` package. Have a look [here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/sn/html/dsn.html). However, you might need to match your parameters of interest to the input arguments in those functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are an infinite number of distributions that have a given mean, standard deviation, and skew.  The skew-normal distribution is just one of them:

[image: skew-normal]

Comment: Thank you, @DavidG.Stork  Are other parameters that would help me summarize a skewed dataset?